# Adding a monorepo as dependency

Tags: git, github, npm, kendo-ui, monorepo

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this monorepo thing.

Let's say I'm interested in this [monorepo](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-themes). How do I add it as a dependency to my project? It doesn't have a package name.

To provide even more info, I'm only interested in this [package](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-themes/tree/develop/packages/bootstrap) that belongs to that monorepo.

How can I install it?

Comment: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-themes/blob/develop/packages/bootstrap/README.md

Comment: I don't have a problem with how to use it, my problem is how to manage it as a dependency.

Comment: It doesn’t look to be available separately on npm, consider adding it to your package.json using the git url.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to install via NPM.

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap
```